# Let $S$ a non-empty set, $(A,+,\cdot)$ a ring and $f:S\to A$ a bijection. Defined the operations $x*y$ and $x\,\Delta\,y$, is $(S,*,\Delta)$ a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $S$ a non-empty set, $(A,+,\cdot)$ a ring and $f:S\to A$ a bijection. To $x,y\in S$, we define the operations this way:

$x*y=f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))$ and $x\,\Delta\,y=f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))$.

Verify that $(S,*,\Delta)$ is a ring.

I'm having trouble to deal with those functions inverted.

In the association's proof, we have
$(x*y)*z=[f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y)]*z=f^{-1}(f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))+f(z))$

and

$x*(y*z)=x*[f^{-1}(f(y)+f(z))]=f^{-1}(f(x)+f^{-1}(f(y)+f(z)))$

So, I think I need to show that $$f^{-1}(f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))+f(z))=f^{-1}(f(x)+f^{-1}(f(y)+f(z)))$$ and i don't know how to do it.

Could you guys give me a hint?

Comment: When unfolding the definition of $*$ in $[f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))]*z$ you should apply $f$ to both operands, cancelling the $f^{-1}$ to give $f^{-1}((f(x)+f(y))+f(z))$.

Comment: But can I say that $f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))$ is equals to $f^{-1}(f(x))+f^{-1}(f(y))$??

Comment: Since the question has carefully used different notation for the operations on $S$ and $A$, it may help to keep track of which set each expression belongs to. For example $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and $f^{-1}(f(y))=y$ are elements of $S$, so $f^{-1}(f(x))+f^{-1}(f(y))$ is not defined. You can say that $f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))=f^{-1}(f(x))*f^{-1}(f(y))$ (just use the definition of $*$).